# Use input for update message in a Teams Flow - Post Adaptive Card action

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, power-automate

With the "Post an adaptive card" action in Flow / Power Automate -> Microsoft Teams there's the option to specify an "update message" following the user response to the card.

How can I access the data inputs and the submitActionId for use in this message?

The use case is as follows:

- user receives the card and enters data into a textfield.
- user clicks one of two buttons (similar to "approve" and "reject")
- (what I want to do:) card is updated to show what text the user entered and which button was pressed.

I can access other dynamic data that have been created by previous actions in the "update message" field. But the output of this adaptive card action itself is not available "within" the action, not by normal means anyway. Later in the flow it's necessary to parse the JSON output of this action.

Supplementary question: Is it possible to style the "update message". Currently it appears all bold.

Supplementary info: the "update message" field does not appear to accept another adaptive card (would have been logical...). If I enter adaptive card json there, it just gets spat back out literally in Teams.

Comment: @peter Campbell, You can parse your response using "Parse JSON". Follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-adaptive-cards?source=docs).

Comment: Sure, but that's too late to provide input to the "Update Message" field in the "Post an adaptive card" action.